# Proof of residence

Tags: united-kingdom, residency

I lived and worked in Great Britain for a few years and was living in temporary housing and shared houses while waiting for a council house. My latest temporary address was in London. Then I moved to the Netherlands. I now need proof of the addresses where I lived in Great Britain before my immigration. Where and how can I apply for such a document (proof of residence)?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the local authorities/organisations that dealt with your temporary housing arrangements?

Comment: I edited your use of the word 'emigration' to 'immigration', which I believe from the nature of your post is the term you actually meant.